# date formatter obj c ignoring my date

Tags: ios, objective-c

It seems like the dateformatter in obj c is ignoring my date. The string I'm entering is "05:18 August 5 2018 PM" however it's returning "2018-08-06 00:18:00 +0000".

Here is the code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm MMMM dd y a"];
[dateFormat setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
NSDate *newDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:self.fullDateAndTime];
```

Comment: Where do you leave? Do you leave in a place which has 7 hours differences from GMT (West Coast of the US/Canada)? And when it's 5PM (~ 17h), it's midnight at GMT?

Comment: @Larme California

Comment: So it's the same date. Because if you convert your "hour" to UTC, it's the correct one. Look that "+0000", it's saying no difference from UTC. So it seems to be the same date to me.